# float left and right make 2 column to be same height

Tags: html, css

Why height 100% for the right floated column can't make it 100% height? Now i'm confused what 100% height really means.

https://jsfiddle.net/7ybLa9fj/

How to make 2 column to have equal height if I'm using float?

```css
.wrap {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background: #fafafa;
  text-align: center;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%; //make right has the same with left doesn't work
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="left">
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>

  </div>
  <div class="right">right content is not</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap uses floats so the solutions in my linked dupe would answer this question.

Comment: @Paulie_D Agree it does has an answer, though still not explain why. Feel free to close it again and I will leave it be :)

Comment: I don't think I can close again now but you might be able to

Comment: @Paulie_D Try... if not, I lost the link so post it as a comment and i will

Comment: Its still shown in the Linked Questions sidebar

Comment: @Paulie_D Missed that ... mission complete :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using percent for height, also the ascendants need a height, all the way to the `html`, unless one have a fixed height, i.e. viewport units `vh`, shown in sample 2

Sample 1, with `height: 100%` on the `html, body`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background: #fafafa;
  text-align: center;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  background: white;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="left">
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>

  </div>
  <div class="right">right content is not</div>
</div>
```

Sample 2, with `height: 100vh` on the `wrap`

```css
.wrap {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background: #fafafa;
  text-align: center;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  background: white;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="left">
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>

  </div>
  <div class="right">right content is not</div>
</div>
```

---

Updated

Also, a more modern way to do something like that is to use Flexbox instead of `float`, much more responsive and elegant coding.

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
}

.left, .right {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="left">
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>
    <p>
      left content is long
    </p>

  </div>
  <div class="right">right content is not</div>
</div>
```

Comment: any disadvantage using vh?

Comment: @JennyMok In this case, no.

Comment: @JennyMok I updated my answer and also added a couple of duplicates to draw more attention to these answers/question

Comment: in what case vh has problem? Never use it but it worked anyway in this case haha.

Comment: @JennyMok It doesn't have any problem, though as it is based on the viewport it can sometimes have a disadvantage for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

Height 100% will take the height as 100% to its parent element if the element inside the div need that much height.

In Your case right div have only one element which dont need this much big height to render.

IN case you want both left and right container to be of same height kindly provide height in px like below

```
.left{
height:200px
}
.right{
height:200px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add 100% to be same height, because the element have floa right is not have childrens like element before. And 100% is mean, the height as 100% height children. So you must set the height with 375px to be same height.

```
.right {
height:375px;
}
```

See at Js fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/7ybLa9fj/1/